# Sending message to private MSMQ queue with Authenticate checkbox checked?

Tags: .net, wcf, msmq, msmqintegrationbinding

Before posting this question, I searched through all forum threads. I found that my issue is similar to the [Sending to authenticated queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184104/sending-to-authenticated-queue) However that thread doesn't really answered my question.

I have following setup (using .NET applications and MSMQ)

- Installed **MSMQ with Active Directory Services Integrated mode** on my Windows7 64 bit machine.
- I have created two private Queues (PQ1 and PQ2) as a Transactional queues and configured its Security tab to give full access to domain user id (domain user id which is also Administartor on Win7 machine).
- In my project I have three .NET 4.0 applications which are hosted by Windows Service (running with the access rights of same domain user id) on this Windows 7 machine
- First .NET application is running on its own thread that reads data from database and sends MSMQ message to PQ1 queue
- Second and third are WCF applications (say wcfA and wcfB) self hosted from Windows service.
- wcfA and wcfB are configured for MsmqIntegrationBinding with Transport security mode with properties  mqAuthenticationMode set to "WindowsDomain" and msmqProtectionLevel set to "EncryptAndSign"
- wcfA picks up messages from PQ1 and then processes the message and send another MSMQ message to PQ2
- wcfB picks up the messages from PQ2 and proccesses it

Note that everything works OK in above setup.

**However the issue starts when I enable the "Authenticated" checkbox for the private Queues PQ1 and PQ2 on its General tab**. After this settings, the first application sends the MSMQ message to private queue but it ends up in "Transaction dead-letter messages" queue. 
I tried adding **Authenticated Users** group to the Queue security tab and giving full access but it did not work.

Further to this I also observed that the Sender tab on Property page of the message that goes to dead-letter queue reads **Authenticated: No**

Your help is highly appreciated to make the applications work with Authenticated Queue.

Comment: how does the .config file look like for the msmq binding?

Comment: Here is the binding configuration for WCF service: <msmqIntegrationBinding >
<binding name="wcfA_MsmqBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" exactlyOnce="true" durable="true" receiveRetryCount="2" retryCycleDelay="00:00:20" maxRetryCycles="2" receiveErrorHandling="Move"                    deadLetterQueue="System">
  
<security mode="Transport" >
  <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqProtectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
   </security>
                </binding>             

            </msmqIntegrationBinding>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After initializing a `Message` object, set the
`UseAuthentication` property to `true`.

Example for sending a message to an authenticated queue:

```
private void SendToQueue(string queueMessage)
{
   var message = new System.Messaging.Message(queueMessage);
   message.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;            

   // This line resolved issue for sending message to queue with Authenticate checkbox checked. 
   message.UseAuthentication = true; 

   var queue = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=OS:.\private$\PQ1");
   queue.Send(message, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
}
```